# postion background and text when going responsive

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I have 2 columns using foundation and the only what to get the images to site just like I want is the following code and css. my problem is I cannot get the text and info to go ontop of the image and stay center.

go here https://www.battlefield.com/ and under the introduction section those 2 columns is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have tried flex and block if the image is set as background of the column it does not respond as I want

```css
   .what{
        max-height: 428px;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
    }

    .nopad{
     padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <body>
    <div class="row expanded">
     <div class="columns medium-6 what nopad"><img src="http://media-www-battlefieldwebcore.spark.ea.com/content/battlefield-portal/en_US/_jcr_content/par/panelgrid/panels/panel/backgroundImage/image/xlarge.img.jpg"></div>
     <div class="columns medium-6 what nopad"><img src="http://media-www-battlefieldwebcore.spark.ea.com/content/battlefield-portal/en_US/_jcr_content/par/panelgrid/panels/panel_0/backgroundImage/image/xlarge.img.jpg">
      </div> 
  </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to center an element over your image.

```css
.what {
  max-height: 428px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.nopad {
  padding: 0px;
}

.info {
   position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="row expanded">
    <div class="columns medium-6 what nopad">
      <img src="http://media-www-battlefieldwebcore.spark.ea.com/content/battlefield-portal/en_US/_jcr_content/par/panelgrid/panels/panel/backgroundImage/image/xlarge.img.jpg">
      <p class="info">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="columns medium-6 what nopad">
      <img src="http://media-www-battlefieldwebcore.spark.ea.com/content/battlefield-portal/en_US/_jcr_content/par/panelgrid/panels/panel_0/backgroundImage/image/xlarge.img.jpg">
      <p class="info">text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to place the text on top of the image:

```
.text {
  z-index: 100;
}
img {
  z-index: -1;
}
```